# match same pattern at begin and end twice

Tags: python, regex

I need to change words in upper case for a tag `'###'`. Let's suppouse a charset like this in all the text: `[a-zA-Z\s]`

I'm doing this:

```
re.sub(r'(^|\s)([A-Z]+)(\s|$)', r'\1###\3', 'Hello PYTHON WORLD')
```

but instead of getting `'Hello ### ###'`, it returns `'Hello ### WORLD'`.

The problem is that re.sub matches all occurrences, however, groups 1 and 3 are *equals*, but re.sub isn't using it twice to match PYTHON and WORLD.

How do I solve it? I'm using python 3.

*equals*: almost equals, they differ in `^` and `$` in case of begin/end, but this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace all *upper-case* words with `###` use the following approach:

```
s = 'Hello PYTHON WORLD'
replaced = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z]+)\b', r'###', s)
print(replaced)
```

The output:

```
Hello ### ###
```

*`\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string*

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
re.sub(r'([A-Z]+(\s|$))', r'###\2', 'Hello PYTHON WORLD')
```

Comment: This won't work because also replaces 'hellO pythON' as '###'

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the spaces that are matched in `(\s|$)` and `(^|\s)` overlap between the two words. That means the third word will be replaced:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s[A-Z]+\s', r' ### ', 'Hello WORLD PYTHON WORLD')
'Hello ### PYTHON ###'
```

Which means you don't want to include the spaces themselves in your search. For that you can use lookup assertion, like in the following example:

```
re.sub(r'(?!(^|\s))([A-Z]+)(?=(\s|$))', r'###', 'Hello PYTHON WORLD')
'Hello ### ###'
```